# Promises.all not fulfilling before function returns

Tags: javascript, promise

I've been wrestling with this for a bit and I'm not sure of a next step. I'm trying to make am async DB call inside a `switch` statement. Now, I know it won't fulfill the promise in time if I put it inside the statement itself so I've created an array of the calls and am trying to resolve them all prior to building the object that gets returned. Right now, I'm just returning the empty array of `failed_tests` because `Promise.all` isn't finishing prior to building the object.

```
function getMetrics(num_tests, env)
{
  return new Promise((fulfill, reject) =>
  {
    elastic.getMostRecentResults(num_tests, env).then(results =>
    {
      var promises = [];
      var num_failed = 0,
          num_passes = 0,
          num_skipped = 0,
          failed_tests = [];
      results.aggregations.tests.buckets.forEach(bucket =>
      {
        switch(bucket.most_recent_result.hits.hits[0]._source.status)
        {
          case "passed":
            num_passes++;
            break;

          case "skipped":
            num_skipped++;
            break;

          case "failed":
            num_failed++;
            var full_id = bucket.most_recent_result.hits.hits[0]._source.full_id;
            promises.push(getResultsForFailedTest(full_id, env));

            break;

          default:
            break;
        }
      });

      console.log(promises.length);

      Promise.all(promises).then(results => {
        failed_tests.push(results)
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      });

      var metrics = {
        "total_tests": num_tests,
        "num_pass": num_passes,
        "num_skip": num_skipped,
        "num_fail": num_failed,
        "failed_results": failed_tests
      };

      fulfill(metrics);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Why not put your call to `fulfill` inside of your `Promise.all` callback?

Comment: When you build your `metrics` variable and then call `fulfill` that is happening before `.then` is called for `Promise.all`. Try putting `fulfill` and your creation of `metrics` inside of the `.then` function call.

Comment: This really depends on what `getResultsForFailedTest` returns, hopefully a promise, but you probably wanted to either `return promise.all...` or call  `fulfill` in the callback for `promise.all` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
  Promise.all(promises).then(results => {
    failed_tests.push(results)
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  });

  var metrics = {
    "total_tests": num_tests,
    "num_pass": num_passes,
    "num_skip": num_skipped,
    "num_fail": num_failed,
    "failed_results": failed_tests
  };

  fulfill(metrics);
```

to:

```
  Promise.all(promises).then(results => {
    failed_tests.push(results)
    var metrics = {
      "total_tests": num_tests,
      "num_pass": num_passes,
      "num_skip": num_skipped,
      "num_fail": num_failed,
      "failed_results": failed_tests
    };

    fulfill(metrics);
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  });
```

Reason being, metrics is being created and `fulfill` is being called before the function within your `.then` statement is executed.

Comment: Yeah. That was it. Thanks. I thought I had tried this, but I think I was leaving the fulfill outside the `.then`